# Numpy.ma: Keep masked array linked to its building blocks (shallow copy?)

Tags: python, numpy

If you are building a masked array, its :

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, data, mask):
        self.masked_array = numpy.ma(data, mask=mask)
```

What I would like is for mask and data to change when I change the masked array. Like:

```
data = [1,2,3]
mask = [True, False, False]
c = myclass(data, mask)
c.masked_array.mask[0] = False  # this will not change mask
```

The obvious answer is to link the after building the object:

```
c = myclass(data, mask) 
data = c.masked_array.data
mask = c.masker_array.mask
```

And, although it works, in my non-simplified problem it is quite a hack to do just for this. Any other options?

I am using numpy 1.10.1 and python 2.7.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask is itself a numpy array, so when you give a list as the mask, the values in the mask must be copied into a new array.  Instead of using a list, pass in a numpy array as the mask.

For example, here are two arrays that we'll use to construct the masked array:

```
In [38]: data = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [39]: mask = np.array([True, False, False])
```

Create our masked array:

```
In [40]: c = ma.masked_array(data, mask=mask)

In [41]: c
Out[41]: 
masked_array(data = [-- 2 3],
             mask = [ True False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Change `c.mask` in-place, and see that `mask` is also changed:

```
In [42]: c.mask[0] = False

In [43]: mask
Out[43]: array([False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

It is worth noting that the `masked_array` constructor has the argument `copy`.  If `copy` is False (the default), the constructor doesn't copy the input arrays, and instead uses the given references (but it can't do that if the inputs are not already numpy arrays).  If you use `copy=True`, then even input arrays will be copied--but that's not what you want.

Comment: Correct answer + not working in the question = Wrong question asked :)  Meaning that you are absolutely right, but my problem is located somewhere else, thanks a lot!